how to delete role template in cloud foundry
I have a CAPM application deployed to cloud foundry with xssecurity role templates. I have added default attribute values in the attribute reference section like this   "attribute-references": [ {
"name" : "TransportationPlanningPoint",
"default-values" : ["0822"]
}]. Now I want to either remove the default values or delete this role and create a new one with the same name
I tried to remove the attribute values fromxs security file and redeployed the application but it didnt work
